# List hidden files but exclude directories.

Tags: command-line, zsh

Is there a way to list files, but not directories, prefixed with a `.` (hidden files)?

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -ld .?* |grep -v ^d
```

This lists all dot files but no directories...

Answer (score 1):

Just run the below find command on the directory where the files you want to print are stored.

```
find . -name ".*" -type f
```

Comment: Isn't the question to *list* files instead?

Comment: yep, op wants to list the files ...

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` you just can use the *Glob Qualifier* `(.)`:

```
ls .*(.)
```

Usually `.*` matches any file or directory starting with a `.`. `(.)` qualifies the `*` glob to match only plain files. `.*(/)` would match any directory starting with `.` and `.*(^/)` matches any "non-directory" like files and symbolic links (including those pointing to directories).

For more information on *Glob Qualifiers* have a look at `man 1 zshexpn`.